# Joomla javascript(JQuery) accordion menu always expand all nodes when click on last child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to joomla and Jquery. Please take this in mind.

I've a javascript accordion menu that is not working well: when I click on the last child element, then all nodes appears expanded. Not only the node(father) of the children clicked.

I've the index.php of the template that shows:

```
function initMenu() {
        $('.menu ul').hide();
        $('.menu li.active.parent ul').show();
        $('.menu li a').click(
        function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
        }
        );
        }
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

[I can't post the images that I edited to show the behaviour(because I don't have reputation), so I'll explain the situation with a concept menu]

**Behaviour shown:**

Node1
|||||Node1.1
|||||Node1.2
||||||||||||Node1.2.1
**|||||||||||||||||||||Node 1.2.1.1**<----- Clicking here all nodes below are expanded!
|||||Node1.3
Node2
|||||Node2.1
||||||||||||Node2.1.1
||||||||||||Node2.1.2
||||||||||||Node2.1.3
|||||||||||||||||||||Node2.1.3.1
|||||||||||||||||||||Node2.1.3.2
|||||||||||||||||||||Node2.1.3.3
Node3

**Correct Behaviour:**

Node1
|||||Node1.1
|||||Node1.2
||||||||||||Node1.2.1
**|||||||||||||||||||||Node 1.2.1.1** <----- Clicking here don't show any more childs
|||||Node1.3
Node2
Node3

Any help on this will be apreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First of give us some html code, I guess that you are not quite correctly all you nodes
As I guess Node 1.2.1.1 handles the rest of your nodes as 1 entity

Secondly,Joomla by core includes mootools framework , maybe there is a conflict
Try to wrap your code with

```
$.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
```

Least but not last, try using [JqueryUI's accordion plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) It's really easy to use

Comment: It's a Joomla template, and honestly I don't know where the html code is generated (I'm on it).

Besides, I'm new to Jquery, and I don't know If I can use, the JQueryUi version..but I'll try.

Thanks for the tips, I'll post the results.